# MailChimp Unsubscribe in PHP

Tags: php, mailchimp

I am having a terrible time trying to sort out unsubscribe from MailChimp via PHP.

I'm using mailchimp-api-php [link to repo](https://bitbucket.org/mailchimp/mailchimp-api-php)

I haven't been able to track down any examples of unsubscribe code, but using the API and the php code in the wrapper provided, I've put this together, which seems correct to me:

```
$unsub = $Mailchimp_Lists->unsubscribe(
    $list_id,
    $email,
    true, //delete_member
    true, //send_goodbye
    false //send_notify
);
```

The PHP error I now get is:

```
Uncaught exception 'Mailchimp_List_MergeFieldRequired' with message 'FNAME must be provided - Please enter a value.
```

Nowhere in the API docs does it mention needing or even a place to include FNAME in the unsubscribe function. I'm just lost here and desperately hoping somebody can light the way.

Comment: Looking at the repo, your function should work as long as the parameters are correct. Make sure the variable `$email` is actually an array ( `array( 'email' => 'duffy@dolan.com' )` and the other variables like $list_id and $MailChimp are what you expect them to be. Its hard to verify them without seeing more of the code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at their documentation, here: https://bitbucket.org/mailchimp/mailchimp-api-php/src/7ac99b5ac746d5875c5c350ad7e3b83674c83ec1/src/Mailchimp/Lists.php?at=master#cl-747 - the unsubscribe method expects the second parameter to be an array with an email key. Write your code like this:

```
$unsub = $Mailchimp_Lists->unsubscribe(
    $list_id,
    array('email' => $email),
    true, //delete_member
    true, //send_goodbye
    false //send_notify
);
```